# Адаптация дизайна на iOS

Tags: photoshop, xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день.
Есть макет дизайна приложения, при наложения друг на друга полупрозрачных слоев на хcode, цвет бара становится тусклый. В [скриншоте](http://yadi.sk/d/KoJ6MmWIPWn4s) видно как должно быть и как получается. Есть мысли из за чего это?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: это navigationBar, или отдельная вьюха? семерка в "navigation bar" будет по умолчанию ставить свой Blur в зависимости от подложенного цвета.

Answer (score 1):

А что у бара с прозрачностью и альфой? Насколько помню прощрачность включена в 7-ке по умолчанию, что с альфой надо смотреть, может у вас накладывается прозрачность картинки на прозрачность самого бара, вот и получается все очень бледным